# crystal report 7 export to excel Max

Tags: excel, crystal-reports, export-to-excel

The crystal report i use has excel 5.0 which has a limit of 16384 rows, what can i do when the information being exported exceeds this number. 
The problem is that once it reaches the limit other data gets cut off which is not cool

Any suggestion would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can place a warning in the report header so the interactive user is warned of the cutoff. Another possibility is to prompt the user for a section number and filter rows in blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following steps

1) Firstly find the total record either from a running total or from report data source data table end.

2) When export data exceed the limit then create another excel file after exporting data from crystal report and place remaining data in that file, you have to do this thing in your code.

3) Give a message to the user that exported data created two files.